# How to Add/Edit the Iteration Field in Team Foundation Server Scrum v1.0 beta Workflow

Tags: tfs

I downloaded and installed the new Team Foundation Server Scrum v1.0 beta work template from Microsoft.  I would like to edit the drop-down that displays in the Iteration field used when entering a new Sprint work item.  If I enter in a release / sprint number that does not exist I get the following message:

> "New Sprint 1: TFS20017: The area or iteration provided for field 'Iteration Path' could not be found"

Does anyone know where I need to go to edit this listing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. Connect to TFS.
2. In the Team Explorer, select the team project you want to define the iterations for.
3. Click on the `Team` menu item in the Visual Studio menu bar.
4. Choose the `Team Project Settings` sub-menu
5. Choose `Areas and Iterations...`
6. Add sub-nodes as necessary for areas or iterations.

Areas and Iterations are defined on a per-project basis, so if you are in one team project when you define them, you won't be able to access them from another team project.

Comment: I actually found it as well.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thank you for the note that they are per-project.

Comment: In VS 17 it is: Team > Team Project Settings > "Work Item Areas and Iterations..."

Answer (score 4):

In TFS Version 16 do as follow:

1. Click on your **collection** top the left menu
2. In the project, list click on your **project**
3. Click on **setting gear** on the top right toolbox
4. Click on the **work tab**
5. In this page, you will see the iteration list, add a **new child** to your Location
6. after add new child click on the **default team's settings**.
7. click on **iterations**, select newly added iterations to appear on board list.

That's All, happy coding.