# Change Iteration cycle name in Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, iteration

I'm currently working with Test Manager Version 2010.
When running a testcase with multiple iterations in it, a list is shown in the top left corner which has the following:

- Iteration 1
- Iteration 2
- Iteration 3
- ....

My question is, is it possible to change this name to any subject so that it is easier to remember the meaning behind every iteration?

For example:

- Iteration1 needs to be named Cat
- Iteration2 needs to be named Dog
- And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no :) I've never done this from the test manager, but here is a post that says how you change the iterations using the team explorer. You can name them whatever you want, they are nothing more than strings in a hierarchy. Even though the problem is slightly different than yours the steps should apply.

[How to Add/Edit the Iteration Field in Team Foundation Server Scrum v1.0 beta Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135459/how-to-add-edit-the-iteration-field-in-team-foundation-server-scrum-v1-0-beta-wo)

The bad news is that TFS uses loose coupling on the work items. that meens that whenever you change something like this the workitems that have used the old string will still have the old value. you will either make a script to update all work items, or manually go in and select the new value for each and every work item. If you only use the new values for new test cases (or other work item types) you're good to go.